# Assign proper function to the object of a class

Tags: java, function

I have a clas called as `MyFunctions` that defines different functions `func1`, `func2`, etc. Also I have a class `Process` that stores the function name assigned to the object of this class:

```
Process p1 = new Process();
String fName1 = "func1";
p1.setFunctionName(fName1); 
Process p2 = new Process();
String fName2 = "func2";
p2.setFunctionName(fName2);
```

In order to run a proper function, I do the following:

```
MyFunctions f = new MyFunctions();
if (p.getFunctionName() == "func1") {
   output = f.func1(inputdata);
} else if (p.getFunctionName() == "func2") {
   output = f.func2(inputdata);
}
```

I´m not sure that this approach is efficient. Is there any other way to solve this task?

Another question: is it possible to do something like this in JAVA?:

```
String fName = p.getFunctionName();
output = f."+fName+"(input);
```

Comment: Functions sadly are not Objects in Java. You might look at Reflection, though.

Comment: Have a look at the strategy pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91932/how-does-the-strategy-pattern-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this approach is not exactly correct. Never use `==` to compare objects. Use `equals()` instead:

```
MyFunctions f = new MyFunctions();
if ("func1".equals(p.getFunctionName())) {
   output = f.func1(inputdata);
} else if ("func2".equals(p.getFunctionName())) {
   output = f.func2(inputdata);
}
```

Second, I'd suggest you to use `enum` instead.

```
public enum FunctionInvoker {
    func1 {
        public Object invoke(MyFunctions o, Object ... arg) {
             o.func1(arg[0]);
        }
    },
    func2 {
        public Object invoke(MyFunctions o, Object ... arg) {
             o.func2(arg[0], arg[1]);
        }
    },
}
```

Now the usage looks like:

```
String functionName = ...; // probably read from file, etc.
Object result = FunctionInvoker.valueOf(functionName).invoke(args);
```

Comment: Object result = FunctionInvoker.valueOf(functionName).invoke(args);
I changed it to ...invoke(new MyFunctions(),args); But still I cannot compile the code. It says that the method ´invoke´ is undefined.

Comment: It started working after including: public abstract Object invoke(MyFunctions o, Object args);

Answer (score 1):

Java's [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) will most likely be useful to you. It allows you (among other things) to find methods in classes at runtime (when you have for example the method name in a string) and call methods that way.

A simple example:

```
String inputdata = "Hello";

// Finds the method "func1" in class MyFunctions that takes a String argument
Method method = MyFunctions.class.getMethod("func1", String.class);

// Calls the method on a new MyFunctions object, passing in inputdata
// as the argument
Object result = method.invoke(new MyFunctions(), inputdata);

System.out.println("Return value: " + result);
```

Comment: It says: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cpn_logic.MyFunctions.func1(java.lang.String)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Does your class really have a method `func1` that takes a `String` argument? It was just an example of how to use the reflection API, not to be taken literally. You must adapt it for your own program.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a determined set of functions, then use `public static` constants to declare the names of the functions.

Example:

```
public static String FUNCTION1 = "func1";
public static String FUNCTION2 = "func2";
```

For you second question, yes it is possible using java [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to find the function to execute.

For instance:

```
f.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(p.getFunctionName).invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I´m not sure that this approach is efficient. `MyFunctions f = new MyFunctions();`
>   `if (p.getFunctionName() == "func1") {`

No. AFAIK it will not work. You are comparing references of String instead of comparing it's content.

```
if (p.getFunctionName() == "func1")
```

use `.equals` instead of `==` to compare 2 strings.

---

> is it possible to do something like this in JAVA? `output = f."+fName+"(input);`

You can use [reflection in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use an enum to decouple:

```
public enum Function {
ONE {
public void call(Functions functions) {
functions.func1();
},
TWO {
...
};
```

public abstract void call(Functions functions);
}

An the process:

```
Process p1 = new Process(Function.ONE);
MyFunctions f = new MyFunctions();
p1.call(f);
```

Hope you got the idea :)