# Is there more elegant method for multiple conditions verification

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

Case:
ASP.NET MVC, C# and ExtJS. A user has got a filter, where he can choose multiple values. There is 13 such filters and a user can add them or remove from the UI.

Problem:
On the server side I've got this class for getting filters values:

```
public List<string> Filter1 { get; set; }
public List<string> Filter2 { get; set; }
...
public List<string> Filter13 { get; set; }
```

Then I select data from a database and convert it to `IEnumerable<DataClass>` where `DataClass` is looks like below:

```
public string Data1 { get; set; }
public string Data2 { get; set; }
...
public string Data13 { get; set; }
```

Then I filter this data like this:

```
if (filter.Filter1 != null && filter.Filter1.Any()) {
    data = data.Where(x => filter.Filter1.Contains(x.Data1));
}
...
if (filter.Filter13 != null && filter.Filter13.Any()) {
    data = data.Where(x => filter.Filter13.Contains(x.Data13));
}
```

So there are 13 `if` and 13 basically same filter logic. And this code is looks horrible. Is there any way to make more beautiful filter?

**Added:**
Filter1 can by applied only to Data1 and so on.

Comment: can you modify the Filter class?

Comment: @WiiMaxx, where did you find a filter class? There are only properties with `Filter[n]` name.

Comment: sure but you wrote "On the server side I've got this class for getting filters" so i thought `filter` is a object from Filter therefore i asked you if you are able to modify this class

Comment: @WiiMaxx, yes, I can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array:

```
private static const int N = 13;

public string[] Data = new string[N];
public List<string>[] Filter = new List<string>[N];
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if(filter.Filter[i] != null && filter.Filter[i].Any()) {
        data = data.Where(x => filter.Filter[i].Contains(x.Data[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do: you have 13 lists of filtertypes, and if a filter is set (or selected by a user), you get a separate string (f.i. 'data1' for filter1) and try to match on that?

That sounds like something's wrong in the way you set up your datastructure to begin with... you are correct in thinking there may be a better solution when you see this amount of duplicate code :-) maybe you can explain the functionality of what you're trying to actually do?

Having said this, it might be you could benefit from implementing a design pattern like the strategy pattern, where you get a different behaviour (strategy) based on the situation ( [How does the Strategy Pattern work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91932/how-does-the-strategy-pattern-work) ). But it's probably better if you explain first what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I've got a big join for the customer's report, where I selected 13 fields from 13 tables (I can't change the data structure or the report). `DataClass` is represented my selection. And I've got 13 filters. User can add them. After user add filter, it's loaded by possible values. So `Filter1` loaded possible values from the `Table1`. This is the reason, because I can apply `Filter1` only to `Data1`. Example: I select data for a report with 'Country' field. Then add filter 'Country' and select value 'Belgium'. And then the selected value should filter report by the 'Country' field.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're saying but it's hard... But from what I understand, isn't the answer 0699 gave one you could use?

Comment: You don't understand how I described the problem (misunderstanding of the language) or what I described (misunderstanding of the description)?

Answer (score 0):

Use expression trees. It would make your job easier.