# management classes and interfaces Java

Tags: java, class, interface

I have a problem with management classes and interfaces in Java.
I have a interface Superhero and other interface called Human.
Then I have various classe of Human type for example PeterParker.
At the end I have a Interface called HumanAndSuper that has this method:

```
public interface HumanAndSuper{

      public Superhero fromHumanToSuperhero();
      public Human fromSuperheroToHuman();


    }
    public interface SuperHero{

      public void attacks();

   }
```

When I create a Human object,for example PeterParker,in this class I have a private nested Superhero class.
For example:

```
     public class PeterParker implements Human,HumanAndSuper{
         //Constructors

          public Superhero fromHumanToSuperhero(){
              //the human turns into superhero associated
              return new Spiderman();
          }
          public Human fromSuperheroToHuman(){
          //the superhero becomes a human
              return this;
          }
public void speaks(){//It's a example
    //Implementation
}

        private class Spiderman extends PeterParker implements SuperHero{


            public void attacks(){
               //Implementation
            }
         }

        }
```

In practice the implementation of the superhero relative to human is internal to the same class of the human.
what I would like is to be able to instantiate a human with the same variable can pass from human to superhero and vice versa.
For example:

```
PeterParker peter=new PeterParker();//Human
peter.speaks();
peter=peter.fromHumanToSuperhero();//peter becomes spiderman
peter.attacks();//method in Spiderman class
peter=peter.fromSuperheroToHuman();//spiderman becomes Human
```

how can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: `PeterParker` isn't a `SuperHero`, so the assignment `peter = peter.fromHumanToSuperhero();` won't work. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You mean, how to allow a different set of methods in different contexts? That's only possible in Java by casting, or by throwing an exception if a method is not allowed in a certain context (e.g. ``IllegalStateException``). (and probably some more...)

Comment: You should read about Strategy pattern.
Like this [How does the Strategy Pattern work?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91932/how-does-the-strategy-pattern-work

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you're trying to create an instance of a class, and then make that instance become an instance of another class. That's not possible in Java.

However, if you want to change the behaviour of an instance dynamically, I suggest you to look at the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern.

> In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern (also known as
>   Wrapper, an alternative naming shared with the Adapter pattern) is a
>   design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual
>   object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the
>   behavior of other objects from the same class.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: "you're trying to create an instance of a class, and then make that instance become an instance of other class. That's not possible in Java." Are you sure? What about the whole concept of polymorphism? If I have an instance of a String, I can also refer to that as an instance of an Object.

Comment: You can refer to a String instance through an Object variable, but it'll still be a String (which is a particular case of Object).

Comment: A String "is a" Object though.

Comment: The point is that once you create an instance of a class, you can't make it an instance of a different class than the one determined at creation time.

Comment: Andres is right. Decorator may be one of the answers. Another would be AOP for example (pretty close to decorator)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following :

1. Have a `Human` and a `SuperHero` `interface` with their own methods to implement (done)
2. have a `HumanAndSuper` abstract class, which implements the former 2 classes (that's the key here)
3. In your `HumanAndSuper` class, add a private attribute that tells you if you person is currently a human or a superhero, and do the right logic about it
4. In your `Implementation class`, implements your interface methods.

You now have an object (ex: peterParker) who can call all methods, from `Human`, `SuperHero`, and `HumanAndSuper`.

Furthermore, if you want to prevent (for instance) the use of `attack()` when in human form, you'd need to implement the interfaces methods in your `HumanAndSuper` class, and make the right checks (using the private attribute declared above).

There are other (safer) methods to achieve this behaviour, but they're more complicated.